# Wait for Teams to be ready

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I create a team with the new Teams powershell:

```
$t = New-Team -DisplayName $teamname -Description $description -Owner $credential.UserName -Visibility Private -MailNickName $teamalias
```

I would like to apply a custom PnP template to the team's SharePoint site, so I need to know when all items on the site is completely created, otherwise my template script fails. Is there any way to check this by scripting? During the preparation I can see a message in Teams to wait.

Edit: as a workaround, I was thinking to check certain items on the SharePoint site. Does anyone know what is the last item that is created, or is there any kind of property that I could use as trigger?  A tried the "General" folder, didn't work.

Comment: Might sound daft, but could you just use a Start-Sleep and give it plenty of time? I know, I know, it's dirty

Comment: I really would like to avoid this workaround.

Comment: There is no property as such which tells you whether your Teamsite is completely ready. Currently team is working on API's which can tell you if TeamsSite is ready but there is no particular release date that i can share.